# How create userd_id for all users in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models:

```
user: id
has_many :article_users
has_many :articles, through: :article_users

article: user_id
has_many :article_users
has_many :users, through: :article_users

article_user: user_id, article_id
belongs_to: users
belongs_to: articles
```

How to add all users `id` to `user_id` in `article_user` model when creating new article?

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  ...
end
```

Comment: Can you add information about the associations as well please?  I mean i can guess but it;s better to not make people guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new article's user to the current user like so (assuming you have a current_user method)

```
 @article = Article.new(article_params)
 @article.user = current_user
```

I don't understand what you mean by "How to add all users id" - can you expand on what you actually mean by this please?

EDIT: to associate the article with all existing users, you could do something like

```
 @article = Article.new(article_params)
 @article.save
 @article.users << User.all
```

However, this feels like an odd thing to do: it will create a lot of join table records, whereas really it could be summarised with one "bit" of information, eg "can this be accessed by all users?".  What if you make a new user later - that user will not have access to this article.  Do you want them to?

If you want an article to just be "available to all users" rather than "available to the following list of specific users, which might happen to be all users", then you could just add a boolean field to the Article's table called "available_to_all_users" or something.  Then, when you want to find out which articles are available to a given user, you can have a method like this:

```
#in User
def available_articles
  (Article.where(available_to_all_users: true).all + self.articles).uniq
end
```

Comment: I meant that i need to add article not to current user but for all existed users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way to add `user_id` to article_users table for existing records. You have to manually populate the `user_id` using a migration, but if you have `user_id` value in the articles table then there is a chance to add the `user_id`.